# How to use the OSRM front end with leaflet routing machine?

Tags: asp.net, leaflet, osrm, leaflet-routing-machine

I'm new to leaflet and OSRM. I have installed OSRM backend already now I need to display the routing machine with my map. previsouly I was using Leaflet routing machine.

Previous leaflet routing machine:
[image: Previous leaflet routing machine]

Now I need this [image: now i need this]

osrm backend already installed
[image: osrm back end]

Please let me know how can i run this osrm in front end.

Comment: So I guess you've read https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-osrmv1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here [a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/8zg23u5n/) using the leaflet-routing-machine:

[image: animated map]

Here the Javascript code (click on "Full page"):

```js
'use strict';

var map = L.map('mapId');

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(23.5880, 58.3829),
        L.latLng(23.6473, 58.1458)
    ],
    geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
    routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#mapId {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-control-geocoder@2/dist/Control.Geocoder.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-routing-machine@3/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-control-geocoder@2/dist/Control.Geocoder.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-routing-machine@3/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.min.js"></script>

<div id="mapId"></div>
```

Remember to set the `serviceUrl` to your OSRM backend.